# Validation asp.net with bootstrap

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a validation form with asp.net/bootstrap. I'm testing it with one textbox.

Currently this is my code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

</head>

  <body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="form-control" ID="userNameTextBox" />
        <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#form1').formValidation({
                framework: 'bootstrap',
                icon: {
                    valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                    invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                    validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
                },
                fields: {
                    <%=userNameTextBox.UniqueID%>: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The username is required and cannot be empty'
                        },
                        stringLength: {
                            min: 6,
                            max: 30,
                            message: 'The username must be more than 6 and less than 30 characters long'
                        },
                        regexp: {
                            regexp: /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/,
                            message: 'The username can only consist of alphabetical and number'
                        },
                        different: {
                            field: 'password',
                            message: 'The username and password cannot be the same as each other'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I click the button nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?? Thankyou for helping!

Comment: I think you can do validation like this way http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old, but you'll want to use `<%=userNameTextBox.ClientID%>` instead of `<%=userNameTextBox.UniqueID%>` to get the generated ID of the HTML element to reference in javascript. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7197520/564204) for more detail on the different ASP.NET id values.